# how to know position for component android jet-pack compose Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, drag-and-drop, position, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I found that function to drag and drop component like in my code simple image
but now i need to found the x and y axis for that image on screen
like for example when i move it to new position put the new position in variable

```
@Composable
fun ImgLatterMoving(painter: Painter,contentDescription: String) {
    val offsetX = remember { mutableStateOf(0F) }
    val offsetY = remember { mutableStateOf(0F) }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .offset {
                IntOffset(
                    x = offsetX.value.roundToInt(),
                    y = offsetY.value.roundToInt()
                )
            }
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                    change.consumeAllChanges()
                    offsetX.value += dragAmount.x
                    offsetY.value += dragAmount.y
                }
            }
            .size(100.dp)
    ) {
        Image(painter = painter,
            contentDescription = contentDescription,
            modifier = Modifier.clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
        )
    }
}
```